# Grunt - Is it possible to have a task that only runs once ever?

Tags: node.js, shell, gruntjs

There is a particular task that I want to run only once and then guarantee that it is never run again.  Has anyone done this? I was looking at using grunt.event.once(...), or try and detect folders or files using a shell script on postinstall, but both ways leave a task in the gruntfile.js that could potentially be invoked at any time overwriting files.

At a very simple level it would do something like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('setup', [
    'mkdir' // run some setup tasks
]);

grunt.event.once('setup', function() {

    // some how do what's below here so it can't be done again 
    // so not available in config for reuse and possibly overwriting
    // modified files

    grunt.task.run([
        'bowercopy:src_codeigniter'
    ]);
});
```

This even possible in Grunt? I know it's just a task runner, in this case I just want it to run it once.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: https://www.npmjs.org/package/gruntfile-api ?

Comment: Thanks @m90 that will definitely do it.  I can only upvote, but your comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several libraries that let you access a `Gruntfile`'s content via an API so you could use one of these to alter your `setup` task's configuration after it is run the first time.

There's **[Gruntfile Editor](https://github.com/SBoudrias/gruntfile-editor)** and **[Gruntfile API](https://github.com/bezoerb/gruntfile-api)**

While both of them don't support complete task removal you can always modify your tasks configuration this way.